# django-rest-framework-social-auth requires a client secret for convert token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I am making an Android application with a Django based backend.

The Django server has a REST API to serve user data which I want to protect. I only want my users to log in via Google (or FB which I'm going to implement in the future).

I am using django-rest-framework-social-auth to implement the authorization in the backend.

So the flow as I understand is like this:

- The client (my android application), does the whole Google OAuth2.0
  flow and obtains the access token
- The the client then wants to
  convert the Google access token with one with which it can access my
  backend server API endpoints. To do this it calls the `convert-token`
  API endpoint implemented in django-rest-framework-social-auth
- Now that it has the API access token, it can include that in the header of all further API calls and receive the private data.

Now my concern is, the django-rest-framework-social-auth `convert-token` endpoint also needs the `client-id` and `client-secret` generated by django-oauth for the application. So I will have to store the `client-secret` somewhere in my mobile app, which entirely defeats the purpose of authenticating whether the request came from the app or not, because someone can decompile the apk and get the app and make token exchange requests on my app's behalf.

Is there any way around this? Is there a "standard" way to implement this which I don't know?

Comment: Hi, did u come up wid the flow ?? I am stuck in the same issue, for me its azuread